# Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am trying to create a food menu. I am trying to use the custom taxonomies to do this. However, I am struggling to work out the best way to go about this. The idea is to have three levels

- Menu (name)
- Menu Group (Starters, Mains)
- Menu Items

I am trying to use the taxonomies so that they use the pages that get built as they would be perfect for this. I would also need to have these hidden from the posts.

Under the menu group I would need to have a dropdown of the menu and on the items the dropdown of the menu groups.

Is this possible this way or is there are better way?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? You seem to have particular structure in mind and idea how to implement it. There doesn't seem to be much to _answer_ here, without hearing which more specific challenges you have in implementing it.

Comment: My issues are getting them to link together and display as pages under a menu item. I can only seem to get the to attach to a post or custom post type. Which is something I don't want to do.

Comment: A good way to get this question answered would be to provide your code and describe a little better what you have tried to "fix" it, and why it didn't work.